# Custom Field Limits For Managed Packages

Tags: managed-package, custom-field, limits

The [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_general.htm&language=en_US) on global limits says this:

> The custom objects contained in a managed package publicly posted on
>   the AppExchange don't count against the limits for your Salesforce
>   Edition.

Does this mean that any *Custom Fields* associated with these objects also don't count against the limits?

Documentation is unclear.

Comment: According to how the document is structured with the Managed Package clarification being in the same spot as the item being described and with it missing from the custom field, I would read it as yes it counts toward the limit....I am assuming that a managed field on a custom object would have to count toward the limit since the object is not managed......

Comment: @Eric, I'm not sure I understand. For clarification, my hypothetical package contains both Custom Objects and Custom Fields, and I want to know if these fields count towards the limits.

Comment: If the fields are on a managed custom object they why would you think any field would counted toward another custom object not in the package as obviously they would not as they are on your managed custom object.....fields count on a per object basis not per org.....

Comment: The managed package org will have the object and field limits enforced on it. For example you will only be able to create 500 fields on that object in your namespaced org. Once you create your managed package and deploy to a target org you will then be able to add 500 more unmanaged custom fields on that object.

Comment: @Eric. some online documenation says that there is a "total" number of Custom Fields. Eg: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008luUIAQ. Perhaps this is no longer applicable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Custom fields created post-installation, those that do not have a namespace, are counted normally towards that object's limit. As an example, let's say you have managed fields on a standard object A and a managed object B. Your managed fields on A do not count towards that object's total field limit. Similarly, your managed custom fields on B do not count towards B's limit. However, if an administrator creates fields on B after installation, those fields do count towards B's field limit. For example, if B has 100 custom fields, and your organization limit is 500 fields per object, then B can still have 500 custom fields defined on it after it's been installed. If a package upgrade includes more fields later, they will also not count towards the limit during the upgrade process, so installation can't fail even if the maximum limit has already been reached.

Comment: shouldn't that be "... B can still have 400 custom fields..." ?

Comment: @powlo That's not a typo. The point is that managed custom fields don't count towards the limit. If you have 500 custom fields on B in the package, you can still add yet another 500 custom fields on B. In fact, if you have a managed extension package on B, that package can also have 500 fields (and so on, and so forth). There's an upper limit of 10 namespaces per transaction, though, so you can't stack this setup indefinitely.

Comment: Interesting. Does this apply only to "public" AppExchange apps?

Comment: @powlo It applies to any apps that are flagged as "Aloha Apps" (or whatever they're called today). An aloha app is one that has passed the security review, and therefore has an Apex Shield on the AppExchange listing. Technically, it could be a "private" app (e.g. one not findable by searching) as long as it's flagged as an Aloha app. Apps that may be listed publicly but don't have the shield icon count towards the limits normally (assuming that's even allowed anymore?), even if it is a managed package.

Comment: @sfdcfox, is this definitely the case for all managed packages? It seems that managed custom fields on standard objects do count in Sandboxes, but _might not_ in Prod. I'm worried about the inconsistency!

Comment: @WesNolte Any certified managed apps should not count against limits, but managed packages that are not certified do count against the limits. There shouldn't be any difference between a sandbox and production per app, but there's certainly far more apps that do count against limits than those that do not.

Comment: So Salesforce support (partner Premier, so meant to be pretty clueful) told me straight up that the limit did apply across customer and packaged fields, but that there is internal-but-not-roadmapped intention for the limit to operate as sfdcfox says it does today. But on a packaged custom object with 347 packaged fields, I was able to add 170 custom fields (thanks apex-mdapi!) and still add more through the setup UI. In both a Sandbox and a prod org, @wes-nolte.

Comment: I heard the same from a Salesforce employed ISV architect. Still seeing inconsistent behaviour across environments though.