# Do custom fields on standard objects in managed package count towards the total limits for number of custom fields in an org?

Tags: managed-package, custom-field, appexchange

I have read a lot of questions mainly this one : [Custom Field Limits For Managed Packages](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65546/custom-field-limits-for-managed-packages)) posted here but still not able to find a clear answer.

I have a 'security verified' app exchange package that I installed on my dev org, and if I go to the installed package , I see the 'Count towards limits' checkbox checked. 
The same is the case with a non app exchange not security reviewed package version that I installed on another developer org. That also has the 'Count towards Limits' checkbox checked.

There isnt a way for me to test this on Prod environments and other salesforce editions, and I cannot find much documentation on this.

I did find this question : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_distribution_installing_why_do_the_custom.htm&type=0

and from it, I can infer that custom fields, no matter an app exchange package or a regular managed package WILL count towards the limit. The same seems to be case from my developer org tests, but just want to make sure, and confirm from any other documentations as well.

I am only talking about custom fields, my package does not contain any tabs / custom objects etc. Only custom fields on standard objects and a connected app.

Thanks.

Comment: I think your confusion comes from a change in policy. Fields used to not count, but I think they do now. I'm going to have to do a bit of research on this.

Comment: I am also unclear - like sfdcfox says, I remember Aloha Apps where fields didn't count, and when I look in two different Production environment, packaged fields don't seem to be counted towards the Custom Fields Usage number in the Object Limits for Account...but that article seems pretty definite they should be so unclear what the real story is here

Answer (score 0):

Each Edition is allowed a certain number of fields per object; this is a "soft" limit. Packages granted special permission are allowed to exceed those limits, and do not count towards the soft limit. However, each object also has a "hard" limit that cannot be exceeded. This is called out in the [Custom Fields Allowed Per Object](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.custom_field_allocations.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) documentation, which is 900, as of Summer 21, for most standard and custom objects, except for a few, like Activities.